# Issue with installing tensorflow on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install TensorFlow on my windows pc. I haven't been able to find a solution that solves my problem.

I'm currently running python 3.8 64 bit (pip 19.0.3). When trying to install using `pip install tensorflow==2.4.0`, I get the error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.4.0 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.4.0
```

I've tried the method of using the direct package location for both GPU and CPU only:

```
pip install https://storage.
googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

and now get the error

```
tensorflow_gpu-2.4.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

My system is a x64 with an intel i5 and a geforce graphics card. I also have visual studios c++ installed.

Comment: Can you type `where python` in your terminal, to see what kind of python installations you have on your machine? It is possible the default version isn't 3.8 and that causes the error.

Comment: Please run `python --version` and `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"` to check what is Python version and if it's really 64 bit.

Comment: Also, please run `nvidia-smi` so we can see the details of your graphics card.

Answer (score -2):

Have u tried this? :

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: yes i have, it gives the same error as tensorflow==2.4.0